# Can I fly from Taiwan to Thailand?

Tags: thailand, taiwan, covid-19

Not Thai national, not Taiwan national. Passport grants visa exemption.

Airline sold flight.

After buying some Thai friends told me there is a government notice that says that Thai flying from Taiwan into Thailand will need to make a quarantine at home.

What about foreigners? Will I be denied the entry in the country? I have no fever or cough.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently health checks at the airports in Thailand, if you pass and have no fever etc you will not need to be quaranteened, I arrived there from China last week without any issues at all.